# io.emit vs socket.emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm new to socket.io and have run in to something that seems pretty weird. I don't actually know the difference between `socket.emit` and `io.emit` but I can't find an explanation anywhere.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  io.emit('connected')  // <<<< HERE >> socket.emit('connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    io.emit('disconnect')
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

server.listen(3000);
```

That's my server stuff however when I change the `io` to `socket` that message only gets displayed when the user who is connecting connects. `io.emit` sends the message to all users.

Maybe it's supposed to be like that or maybe its just some horrible hack? Let me know if you need the client side HTML.

Comment: It looks like when the io is connected to it creates a socket just for the current users connection. Picture it as a tree where io is at the top and branches off into several sockets.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Here's a supplementary documentation for reference :

```
socket.emit('message', "this is a test"); //sending to sender-client only

socket.broadcast.emit('message', "this is a test"); //sending to all clients except sender

socket.broadcast.to('game').emit('message', 'nice game'); //sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel) except sender

socket.to('game').emit('message', 'enjoy the game'); //sending to sender client, only if they are in 'game' room(channel)

socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', 'for your eyes only'); //sending to individual socketid

io.emit('message', "this is a test"); //sending to all clients, include sender

io.in('game').emit('message', 'cool game'); //sending to all clients in 'game' room(channel), include sender

io.of('myNamespace').emit('message', 'gg'); //sending to all clients in namespace 'myNamespace', include sender

socket.emit(); //send to all connected clients

socket.broadcast.emit(); //send to all connected clients except the one that sent the message

socket.on(); //event listener, can be called on client to execute on server

io.sockets.socket(); //for emiting to specific clients

io.sockets.emit(); //send to all connected clients (same as socket.emit)

io.sockets.on() ; //initial connection from a client.
```

Edit: socket.io docs also contain similar [cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emit-cheatsheet/#server-side).

Comment: at the first line you told socket.emit means sending to sender-client only but in the 9th line you told socket.emit(); //send to all connected clients !!! I don't understand!

Comment: Actually it depends on the need. For instance, on your server you have this line -> socket.emit('message', 'initial message');. This fires up upon script loading. So initially, all connected clients that listen to "message" will display the "initial message" line.

Comment: However, when you have this snippet on your server -> socket.on('message-from-page1', function(message){ socket.emit("message", "response for page 1"); }); and say a client sends a socket.emit('message-from-page1', 'hi from page 1'); and the client also listens to "message", then only that particular client will receive the "response for page 1" line.

Comment: I created a sample for this(though not sure how to share here and simulate), Ping me up so I could quickly demo it. I'll gladly share the code as well.

Comment: Thanks, I get your point now. but it's better to not say `socket.emit(); // send to all connected clients` because the sample you gave for the `"initial message"` is not initiated from a single source of code run for example if you send `socket.emit("initial message"+random)`, everybody gets a different initial message, but for actual broadcasts everybody should get the same number...

Comment: Hey @KentAguilar can you please share the demo with me?

Answer (score 44):

The `io` variable represents the group of sockets. The code you have starts on line one with providing a function in the second parameter that gives you a `socket` variable every time a new connection is made. The `socket` variable is only for communicating with each individual connection. You may not see it in the code but there will be one `socket` variable for each connection established

Comment: great answer on this... question:  so in my Node.js server side code, when I have multiple clients connected via socket.io, and need to send the same data (JSON) out to all clients, if I do io.emit vs socket.emit, is it more efficient and better way to emit?

Answer (score 16):

- `socket.emit` will send back message to sender only,
- `io.emit` will
  send message to all the client including sender
- if you want to send
  message to all but not back to sender then `socket.broadcast.emit`

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question. Here is a sample code that might answer your question.

server.js code:

// Listener for incoming Socket connections

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('send', function(msg){
    console.log('message received/sending: ' + msg);
    io.sockets.emit('new', msg);
  });
});
```

index.html code

```
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        function send(msg) {
            console.log("emitting: " + msg);
            socket.emit('send', { "message": msg });
        }

        socket.on('new', function (msg) {
            console.log("msg " + msg.message);
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg.message));
        });

        $(function () {
            $('form').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                send($('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

In *index.html* `socket.emit('send', { "message": msg });` this line of code actually sends/emits message to server which is waiting to listen on `socket.on('send', function(msg){` this line of code in *server.js*.

Now `io.sockets.emit('new', msg);` this line from *server.js* emits that message to all its sockets and is displayed to users using its listener in *index.html* that is `socket.on('new', function (msg) {`.

Simply said Each socket emits its msg to a server(io is an instance of server) and server, in turn, emits it to all connected sockets. That is how msg sent by any user is displayed to all users. I hope it helps!