# What is the difference between io.emit and io.sockets.emit?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I can't understand what is the difference between io.emit and io.sockets.emit.

Sometimes they behave same but at other times they behave different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**socket.emit**

sends the message to sender-client only

**io.emit**

sendings to all clients, include sender

I got it from here:
[io.emit vs socket.emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674391/io-emit-vs-socket-emit)

Comment: The OP asked about `io.sockets.emit` specifically. That does not seem to be addressed in this answer.